# Change console.log timestamp in react-native or nodejs apps

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-cli

After recent updates the log format in the console on `react-native` and maybe `node` apps, has become like:

[image]

This results after doing a simple `console.log()` call.
In previous versions the timestamp format was different, and a lot shorter. Is there a way to customize that date format?

I know what day is today, time only would save lots of space on my monitor.

I got no luck looking into the docs/source of `react-native-cli`.

Environment: npm 6.14.8, react 16.13.1, react-native 0.63.4

Answer (score 1):

Searching a bit i found 3 ways to check logs:

1. Using android studio, the log format on the logcat can be changed using the settings icon, and you can remove the date
2. Using `react-native log-android` which formats differently the log using the [logkitty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logkitty) package. example scrn of the log prefix outcome:

[image: log-android outcome]

3. The default format on the metro bundler exists inside `node_modules/metro/src/lib/formatLogTimestamp.js`
   It is currently (as of version 0.59):

```
module.exports = date =>
  chalk.dim(
    `[${date.toDateString()} ${date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour12: false
    })}.${String(date.getMilliseconds()).padEnd(3, "0")}] `
  );
```

Change that to:

```
module.exports = date =>
  chalk.dim(
    `[${date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour12: false
    })}.${String(date.getMilliseconds()).padEnd(3, "0")}] `
  );
```

After the change you need to restart metro,
and voila! you have only the time without the date.
[image: log without date]

(Obviously you need to make the change every time you remove/install the metro package)